# Flex line weight of linechart

Tags: apache-flex, linechart, stroke

I want to keep default color of lines and change line weight in Flex LineChart. 
How can I implement it?

Alternatively, if there any method for setting line weight or line color without using LineStroke?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can't do this by declaring something like

```
<mx:Stroke id="anID" weight="3"/>
```

without a color property, and then referencing that in your LineStroke? That works for me.

Comment: Thanks! How about  in ActionScript ?

Comment: private var aStroke:Stroke = new Stroke();
aStroke.weight = 3;

Comment: Sorry. I found that these methods still change color to "black" instead of keep the Flex default color.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like

```
for each (var series: LineSeries in chart.series) {
    (series.stroke as Stroke).weight = 2;
}
```

somewhere in commitProperties() or whatever like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in my application.  Here's how to just change the stroke, and keep all other existing properties:

```
for each (var series: LineSeries in this.lineChart.series) {
    var series_stroke:Stroke = series.getStyle('lineStroke') as Stroke;
    series_stroke.weight = 10;
    series.setStyle('lineStroke', series_stroke);
}
```

Sorry it's a bit late!